# Placing all row pairs in 2d numpy array into a 3d array

Tags: numpy

Consider the numpy 2d array shown:

```
a = [[8, 16, 4, 1, 0, 5],
     [3, 0, 0, 11, 9, 7],
     [5, 5, 8, 5, 15, 5],
     [2, 0, 2, 14, 2, 0],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15]]
```

I want to find all **row pairs** from the array, placing them into a 3d array.  When selecting row pairs, repeat rows are allowed, and the order of the 2 rows is not important.
In the example, there are 15 such 2-row permutations, so I'm hoping to get a 3d array that is 15 layers deep:

```
     [[8, 16, 4, 1, 0, 5],
      [8, 16, 4, 1, 0, 5]],
     [[8, 16, 4, 1, 0, 5],
      [3, 0, 0, 11, 9, 7]],
     [[8, 16, 4, 1, 0, 5],
      [5, 5, 8, 5, 15, 5]],
...etc
     [[2, 0, 2, 14, 2, 0],
      [2, 0, 2, 14, 2, 0]],
     [[2, 0, 2, 14, 2, 0],
      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15]],
     [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15],
      [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15]]]
```

The actual starting arrays can be quite large, so I'm hoping an efficient solution could be suggested.

Comment: Why do you need this ? There might be a better solution for your problem -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you'll have to go outside of `numpy` to get all the pairs, for instance using `itertools.combinations_with_replacement` from the standard library. Example:

```
import itertools
import numpy as np

a = [[8, 16, 4, 1, 0, 5],
     [3, 0, 0, 11, 9, 7],
     [5, 5, 8, 5, 15, 5],
     [2, 0, 2, 14, 2, 0],
     [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 15]]

out = np.array(list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(a, 2)))
```

Comment: I was wondering if slicing (my approach) or pure python would be different in terms of performance and slicing is faster (all happens at lower level). If you're interested in the comparison: [graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlUvI.png)

Comment: Both solutions are clear and fast when applied to larger arrays.   Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.combinations_with_replacement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations_with_replacement) to generate the pairs, then slice:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement

N = 2
idx = np.array(list(combinations_with_replacement(range(a.shape[0]), r=N)))
out = a[idx]
```

Output:

```
array([[[ 8, 16,  4,  1,  0,  5],
        [ 8, 16,  4,  1,  0,  5]],

       [[ 8, 16,  4,  1,  0,  5],
        [ 3,  0,  0, 11,  9,  7]],

       [[ 8, 16,  4,  1,  0,  5],
        [ 5,  5,  8,  5, 15,  5]],

       [[ 8, 16,  4,  1,  0,  5],
        [ 2,  0,  2, 14,  2,  0]],

       [[ 8, 16,  4,  1,  0,  5],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 15]],

       [[ 3,  0,  0, 11,  9,  7],
        [ 3,  0,  0, 11,  9,  7]],

       [[ 3,  0,  0, 11,  9,  7],
        [ 5,  5,  8,  5, 15,  5]],

       [[ 3,  0,  0, 11,  9,  7],
        [ 2,  0,  2, 14,  2,  0]],

       [[ 3,  0,  0, 11,  9,  7],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 15]],

       [[ 5,  5,  8,  5, 15,  5],
        [ 5,  5,  8,  5, 15,  5]],

       [[ 5,  5,  8,  5, 15,  5],
        [ 2,  0,  2, 14,  2,  0]],

       [[ 5,  5,  8,  5, 15,  5],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 15]],

       [[ 2,  0,  2, 14,  2,  0],
        [ 2,  0,  2, 14,  2,  0]],

       [[ 2,  0,  2, 14,  2,  0],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 15]],

       [[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 15],
        [ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4, 15]]])
```